# "fluctuates widely" or "wildly"?

Tags: meaning, etymology, expressions

I think changes to phrases that don't change their meaning are interesting. Example: *an ice cold beer* and *a nice cold beer* mean pretty much the same thing.

I heard another one this morning on the radio in a [story about coal](http://www.npr.org/2011/10/27/141731707/it-s-economy-vs-environment-in-global-coal-trade). The phrase used is *fluctuates widely*, but I know I've also heard *fluctuates wildly*. Looking at [the ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fluctuates%20wildly,fluctuates%20widely&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=0), I'm surprised to see that "widely" is far more popular (although with 0 smoothing, it does fluctuate wildly ;-).

Any idea where either of these phrases comes from, which came first, and/or which is more correct? *wildly* makes more sense to me in most contexts, but *widely* makes sense too.

Comment: Most of the answers here merely assert that the two phrases mean the same thing: I personally would never use "widely" except in reference to a group of ranges any of which in isolation might not fluctuate at all (example: FooBM's stock does not fluctuate wildly, but tech stocks overall fluctuate widely ). "Wide" can imply "broad," where "wild" never can.

Answer (score 28):

Andrew Neely is close, but not quite there:

"Fluctuates widely" means the standard deviation (possible ranges, whatever) is (relatively) huge.

"Fluctuates wildly" means the standard deviation isn't necessarily huge, but it wavers between its two extremes very often.

What you have is a punnet square of possibilities:  Not widely and not wildly, just widely, just wildly, and both widely and wildly.  Choosing whether to use "widely" or "wildly" in speech depends first on whether both apply, and then on which one you want to draw attention to.

**EDIT:**
Jefromi brings up a good point in the comments, that while "wildly" doesn't mean "widely", it's not often used for small, rapid fluctuations.  So I'll include a third option that embodies that description:  "fluctuates rapidly".

Comment: +1 for being correct, and for not having an obligatory n-gram.

Comment: I've never understood the fascination with those when looking for correctness.  Authors generally like artistic license when it comes to wordplay...

Comment: I'd say that wild fluctuations are more often wide - I don't think many people would describe very small but rapid fluctuations as wild. +1, though. It's definitely not just an emotional difference.

Comment: @Jefromi: Hm true.  I think that deserves an addendum

Comment: For engineers and scientists, "rapidly" only makes sense if there's time involved. As this expression is commonly found in textbooks and articles, correct terminology and usage is crucial.

Comment: +1 for a great answer, and especially for the edit. I agree with @Jefromi -- *wildly* is not a word I'd choose for small σ.

Comment: To beg the question a bit, I don't think *widely* implies regularity, so if widely can mean large and irregular, how is that different from *wildly*? *Widely* could mean "large but [in control](http://tinyurl.com/6ap6r2)" and *wildly* could mean "out of control," but I have a strong suspicion that very few people think in terms of statistical control when they use these terms.

Comment: @Caleb: "so if widely can mean large and irregular" - that's what I was attempting to describe with the "punnet square" paragraph.  If both apply, choose the one you want to draw attention to

Comment: Fluctuates widely implies at least some limits; fluctuate wildly does not. Another example of difference: How are the fluctuations today? a) Wide b) Wild. In reality I would use fluctuate wildly to talk about a graph that I can not explain (spikes, questionable limits, periods, etc) and fluctuate widely if I can assume maximums and minimums.

Answer (score 9):

The two phrases mean different things.

Saying something fluctuates widely, the speaker is using an emotionless statistical statement that would be right at home in a dispassionate statistical brief.

Saying something fluctuates wildly is not emotionless.  It is an evocative and emotive statement.  In my mind, saying something is wild brings up pictures of wild animals darting to and fro with a reckless, frenzied abandon.

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wild) says the adverb wild means

> In an uncontrolled manner: "The bad guys shot wild."

Comment: Something that fluctuates "widely" fluctuates over a large range. Something that fluctuates "wildly" fluctuates with rapid and unpredictable changes in direction and speed.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Your comment should be the answer imo, as it is the most significant difference.

Comment: Adding the emotional content is a nice touch, but doesn't make up for missing the inherent distinction in content.

Answer (score 8):

Interesting question! Looking specifically at [NGrams for the period 1700-1903](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fluctuates%20wildly,fluctuates%20widely&year_start=1700&year_end=1905&corpus=0&smoothing=3) I find there are actually only 19 hits for *fluctuates wildly*, as opposed to almost 500 for *widely*. So I guess it's fair to say *widely* was the "original", though I personally always say (and assume I hear) *wildly*.

It's easy to imagine that repeated mishearings and repetitions will cause different subsets of speakers to espouse one form or the other. As @Martin's chart shows, *widely* has been falling out of favour over the last half-century or so. As usual, [British English](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fluctuates%20wildly,fluctuates%20widely&year_start=1890&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3) is a couple of decades behind the US on this one...
[image]

I don't think any significant number of speakers would actually distinguish the two forms as having different *meanings*. I think most speakers are probably like me - they know which version they use themselves, and usually either *hear* that version regardless of what was actually *said*, or assume the other person made a slip of the tongue/didn't know the "correct" form.

EDIT: After a few seconds seconds googling I found [this little gem](http://wealthrat.com/gold-does-not-fluctuate-wildly/). About 20 lines into his diatribe, the author quotes someone saying *[the price of gold] fluctuates so widely* - then a few lines later he takes issue with this, claiming that *Gold does NOT “fluctuate wildly”*. Obviously at least one person agrees with me that these are two versions of the same "set phrase".

Comment: What do you think about these results: http://goo.gl/VBQXl, http://goo.gl/1lNQ9 and finally http://goo.gl/KUmg0 ? ~148,000 vs 6

Comment: It seems likely at least some of those half-dozen instances of *both* being used within one text may reflect differentiation on the part of the writer. But others (as per my example above) clearly don't. After leafing through a few pages of the separate usages, I honestly can't see any real support for the idea of writers making a semantic distinction in general. Scientific/academic usage seems to favour *widely* even more than the overall 6:1 bias, and economic contexts maybe a bit more the other way, but nothing paricularly clear-cut to me, at least.

Comment: ...straw-polling half-a-dozen friends with "fill in the missing blank" for **values fluctuated wi..ly**, I got five *wildly* (the only *widely* was something of a statistician). Nobody mentioned two possibilities until the other one was pointed out *after* they'd made their choice and said what it meant. I still think @Izkata's distinction is largely a post-hoc rationalisation for the fact that this single set phrase has a tendency to slip around a bit.

Answer (score 7):

Exactly, they both make sense. And they are not the same so neither is 'more correct'.

Some graph can fluctuate *wildly* over relatively narrow **range** of values while another can fluctuate *widely* in relatively smooth **way**.

As the fluctuation is more frequently used in technical parlance you would expect a more objectively descriptive 'widely' to go with it.

Comment: I'd expect both to indicate large standard deviation, but *wildly* to imply more randomness. A high amplitude sine wave might fluctuate widely but not wildly. However, I don't think it's safe to read much more than "it changes a lot" into most uses of either phrase.

Comment: In actual usage it looks like there is a lot of overlap, so that these expressions are usually semantically equivalent.  However you are quite correct that *widely* is used more in an academic context where the distinct meanings are more important.

Answer (score 2):

In BE at least it should be "fluctuates wildly"

Although ngrams seems to disagree.

[image]

Comment: That'd be my expectation as an American, too. I was very surprised to see the opposite in the ngram.

Comment: The same majority can be seen when splitting out the Ngrams: when limited to the [American English corpus](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fluctuates+wildly%2Cfluctuates+widely&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3) and the [British English corpus](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fluctuates+wildly%2Cfluctuates+widely&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3). I'm surprised too, but at least we can see the gap has been closing recently.

Comment: It's just not the same phrase, comparison is rather meaningless.

Comment: @Unreason: This is another issue where it would be hard to find a killer argument one way or the other. I'd take an awful lot of convincing before I could accept that these aren't basically two variations of the same "set phrase" where usage fluctuates wildly because of mishearings.

Answer (score 2):

It occurs to me that what's at work here is the evolution of a verbal chimera -- the co-mingling of two different phrases creating something new but not wholly wrong. The two originals likely being:

- varies widely - An example would be ages of people within a group. Across a range, but the individual ages don't suddenly change unpredictably.
- fluctuates wildly - An example being the price of gold, which may go up and down by large and small values, seemingly unpredictable.

They are similar but different which, just like the 'eggcorn', made of bits we're prone to jumble up in our daily speech until it becomes, as we like to say these days, "a thing". And as 'fluctuates widely' does make fair sense, the use isn't corrected, but instead adopted... um... widely. :)

I suspect you'll find instances of 'varies wildly' out in the wild as well.

Answer (score 0):

Both are commonly used, but I believe that "wildly" is more correct.  Consider the dictionary definitions at M-W and dictionary.com:

> to change continually; shift back and forth; vary irregularly: The price of gold fluctuated wildly last month.
>
> to shift back and forth uncertainly

"Wild" fits something that is varying "irregularly" and "uncertainly".   "Wide" does not equate well to either of these terms.

Likewise consider the alternate definition related to a wave:

> to ebb and flow in waves
>
> to move back and forth in waves.

A wave itself is neither "wide" nor "wild".  One can move "wildly", but one cannot move "widely".

Comment: You're right, I did.  Editing.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

In both the examples you give -- ice cold vs nice cold and widely vs wildly -- the words sound similar and the concepts are related, but this does not mean that either case represents the same idea or that one must be derived from the other.

I'll mostly ditto Izkata on the details in this case.

I'd just add that I'm sure I am not saying anything new or surprising when I point out that two words can sound similar but have no relation in either meaning or origin. "ice" is not anything like "rice" despite the fact that the two words sound very similar, etc.

Poets and public speakers may take advantage of such similarities in sound to make an effective turn of phrase. But I wouldn't attach any significance to the similarity in sound per se.

It may be, in any given case, that one of a pair of similar-sounding phrases is a corruption of the other. But not necessarilly; I wouldn't leap to conclusions. You'd have to study the history.

Both "fluctuates widely" and "fluctuates wildly" have coherent meanings, as do "ice cold beer" and "nice cold beer".

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the key difference is that wildly implies unpredictability.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question - where did the phrases come from,  which came first, and which is more correct?  It would make a nice comment though.

Comment: You are correct - point taken. I have insufficient reputation for that, so I probably should have just passed on the comment.

Comment: Well, if you find another couple questions to answer, I would be surprised if you couldn't get enough reputation soon.  (To the point, I've flagged for the post to be turned into a comment; even though you can't post comments, we can turn an answer into a comment.)

Answer (score 0):

People use *wildly* to quantify, as in “they were wildly outnumbered”. Although there are more Google hits for “wildly outnumbered”, I think *widely* is more appropriate as it denotes range and not variance.